# C ++ program only executes first "if" statement

Tags: c++

I was writing a program to process a loan. Problem is that it only reads the first `if` statement and then executes the last sentence of the program that reads `"("Thank you,your loan is being processed")"` How can I correct this? It skips the part where it evaluates user input. Here is the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sstream>
#include<iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>


using namespace std;

int main() {

char landtitle[100];

char Asset[100];
//std::string Asset;

float NumberPlate;
float Year;



char  L[100];
char  t[100];

float amount;

float logbook;
float block;
float PlotNumber;

//float InterestRate;
float LoanAmount;

//LoanAmount = amount * (1+(15/100))*(1+(15/100));
//printf("Amount to be paid after one month is %f",LoanAmount); 


printf("Enter amount you want to borrow");
printf("\nWe wil need an asset for any amount greater than 3M:");

scanf("%d",&amount);


if ( amount > 3000000)
{
    printf("Please choose Asset(use L for logbook or T for title");
    //getline(cin,Asset);
    gets(Asset);
    //cin.ignore();

    if (Asset == "L")
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter logbook number :");
        scanf("%f",&logbook);
        printf("\nPlease enter car Number plate :");
        scanf("%f",&logbook);
        printf("\nPlease enter Year of manufacture :");
        scanf("%f",&logbook);

        //printf("Thank you,your loan is being processed");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter Land title :");
        gets(landtitle);
        printf("\nPlease enter Block :");
        scanf("%f",&block);
        printf("\nPlease enter Plot Number :");
        scanf("%f",&PlotNumber);

        //printf("Thank you,your loan is being processed");
    }



}

else
{
    printf("Thank you,your loan is being processed");
}


}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun. Also C-style string cannot be compared via `==`, so `strcmp()` should be used.

Comment: @MikeCAT.what should i use instead of gets() to capture strings or char.?

Comment: You are using C++, so `std::string Asset; std::getline(std::cin, Asset);` is good.

Comment: The [stack of **warnings**](http://pastebin.com/ehUbuCEN) this code emits is substantial. At a minimum you should start by turning up the warning levels on your compiler to maximum and fix what is flagged first.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d",&amount);
```

You want to scan in as a float, not an integer, so you'll want `%f`

Answer (score 0):

When you compare a string in an array to a string literal, like e.g.

```
Asset == "L"
```

Then the array decays to a pointer to its first element, and the same thing happens to the string literal `"L"`. Then the comparison is between the *pointers* and not the actual strings they point to. That comparison will *never* be true.

To compare strings in C++ you should use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), then you can use simple `==` for equality.

If you want to continue to use C-style strings (i.e. arrays of `char`) then you need to use the [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) function.

Answer (score 0):

your amount is float, but you try to read with integer.

so there will be converted into another numbers.

Comment: I have used std::string "name" for strings but it still skips the part where its supposed to input "Asset" and "DistrictLocation" which are strings.How should i resolve this please ?

Answer (score 0):

Strings(Char Array) can't be compared by `==` sign in C/C++.So when you write
`if (Asset == "L")` 
it actually compares the address allocated to the array(the name of a array points to the first element in array) in memory which can never be equal for two different arrays, so the condition is always false.

Just change this line

```
if (Asset == "L")
```

to

```
if (!strcmp(Asset,"L"))
```

Comment: was using string declarations wrongly.followed the advice here and figured it out.Works like charm.

Comment: will you mention here what u changed in the declaration?